# How to change datetime format values from a queryset in Django?

Tags: django, datetime, highcharts

Let's say I have this query:

```
getall = DataForecast.objects.all().values("date_time", "rainfall_mm_per_10_min", "wl_observed_m",
                                       "wl_forecasted_m")
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(getall),cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```

`date_time` is a `DateTimeField` in my model, the query returns a JSON data in which the date_time format results like this e.g. `"date_time": "2014-01-18T14:00:00"`. Which is in my case, difficult to read. Is there any way to reformat the `date_time` values like this `Jan 18, 2014 02:00 PM`?

I know that I can manipulate the format in my template through e.g.`{{dates.date_time | date:'M d, Y h:i A'}}` but my query returns a JSON data and I am using the data for my [Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/dn0hy1fe/10/).

Here's my model:

```
class DataForecast(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    rainfall_mm_per_10_min = models.FloatField(null=True)
    wl_observed_m = models.FloatField(null=True)
    wl_forecasted_m = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a property called date_time_formatted in the DataForecast model:

```
@property
def date_time_formatted(self):
    return self.date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Replace date_time in getall query with date_time_formatted.

Comment: This is silly, I updated my question and added my model. How do I add that @property? And I need to import in my models.py `datetime`, right?

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'date_time_formatted' into field. Choices are: date_time, id, rainfall_mm_per_10_min, wl_forecasted_m, wl_observed_m` gives me an error.

Comment: My bad. values() only work with fields retrieved directly from the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the value as an annotation function:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Value
...
getall = DataForecast.objects.all().values(
    "date_time", 
    "rainfall_mm_per_10_min", 
    "wl_observed_m", 
    "wl_forecasted_m"
).annotate(
    date_time_formatted=Func(
    F('date_time'),
    Value('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS'),
    function='to_char',
    output_field=CharField()
  )
)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(getall),cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```